# svn: Unable to find repository

Tags: svn, ssh, subclipse

I'm attempting to setup svn on my home network on an Ubuntu server box. I have created the repository on that box using svnadmin create /opt/svn and this was successful. I have installed ssh on this box and want to tunnel svn through ssh so I can open svn through the firewall and check in code on the go.

I am on an ubuntu workstation. I create a host entry called spenser that points to the IP address of my svn server and type

```
ssh spenser
```

to login to the box and create the rsa (or whatever) key on this box. Now I should be good.

So I start eclipse and go into sublipse svn repository browser to create my repository link. I use svn+ssh://spenser. I get the ssh challenge and enter my password. Then I get:

```
    Couldn't find a repository
svn: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'svn+ssh://spenser'
svn: No repository found in 'svn+ssh://spenser'
```

I look at svnserve on the server and I see:

```
thom@spenser:~$ ps aux|grep svn
root      2015  0.0  0.2  11936   640 ?        Ss   08:07   0:00 /usr/bin/svnserve -d -r /opt/svn
```

Which means that it's pointing to the right repository. I look at the repository:

```
thom@spenser:~$ ls -l /opt/svn
total 24
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 2012-01-31 07:03 conf
drwxr-sr-x 6 root root 4096 2012-01-29 12:51 db
-r--r--r-- 1 root root    2 2012-01-29 12:51 format
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 2012-01-29 12:51 hooks
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 2012-01-29 12:51 locks
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  229 2012-01-29 12:51 README.txt
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not an expert in this area, but svn+ssh:// does NOT connect to a running svnserve on the target server.  The svnserve process is spawned in the SSH session itself and tunnelled back to you.  I believe you need to specify svn+ssh://spenser/opt/svn

I refer you to the Subversion book for more information:

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html#svn.serverconfig.svnserve.sshauth

Answer (score 1):

```
# vi /etc/sysconfig/svnserve
```

if not exist create it
and

```
OPTIONS="--threads --root /path/to/svn"
```

Comment: `cat /etc/sysconfig/svnserve` Is what I needed to get unstuck! TY!